# Geolocation prompt before page load?

Tags: javascript, php, html, geolocation

A website I am working on requires users to be able to pay in their local currency, on the basis of an HTML5 geolocation check.  I have set a piece of javascript / html / php up to show a "splash page", which sits over the top of the first page they get to, which says "we think your local currency is : ", and asking them to choose a currency.

At the moment, the browsers' " do you want to share your location " question is appearing after the page is loaded.  Which means that the "we think your local currency is : " part of the page has already done a geo-location check before asking if the user wants to share their information, oddly.

In order to test the geolocation code, I have added the geolocator plug in for firefox, which allows me to give a different html location.  However, I am unable to test this, as the geolocation check is running before the user is asked if they want to share their location.

[image]

Comment: If I understand what you want to do, you either need to delay the popup until after geolocation has called `success` or `error`, or you need to delay the geolocation call until after the user interacts with the popup; don't try to initialise both at page load.

Comment: "you either need to delay the popup until after geolocation has called success or error" - yes, that sounds right, although it would be the load of the entire page.  Any idea how to achieve this in javascript ?  Thanks.

Comment: where is the script located? try making it the first tag within the `<body>`. Other than that, you could hide all the content, then use the `window.onload` event to prompt and unhide the correct stuff...

Comment: The geolocation code is currently situated within the head tag, and is using jquery - $(window).load.  I will try your suggestion and report back.  Thanks.

Comment: I tried the suggestion @WhiteHat, sadly all that happened was that I no longer got the "Share your location" prompt, in chrome anyway.  Thanks for trying though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function success(position) {
  $('#loc').text('We think you\'re at (' +
                 Math.round(position.coords.longitude) + ', ' +
                 Math.round(position.coords.latitude) +
                 '). If not, pick:');
  $('#popup').removeClass('hidden');
}

function error() {
  $('#loc').text('We have no clue where you are, so pick:');
  $('#popup').removeClass('hidden');
}

if ("geolocation" in navigator) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
} else {
  error();
}
```

```css
#popup {
  display: fixed;
  top: 100px;
  left: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
}
#popup.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="popup" class="hidden">
  <div id="loc"></div>
  <button>THE WORLD</button>
  <button>SOMEWHERE ELSE</button>
</div>
```

(for some reason does not work in SO snippet, but works on [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/suyoxahimu/edit?html,css,js,output)